# Function to restore proper/lower case at column level

Tags: ms-access, vba

All text field values in my database had been converted to upper case. I would like to restore, column by column, certain text entries to either lowercase or proper case.

The pseudocode that I have in mind is something like:

```
for each entry in column x of recordset y
entry = strconv(entry,3)
end
```

This would be easier I could simply click on my tables in design view and change a property, but I don't see anything like this.

Comment: (not my down vote, but I can see why)

Comment: I will try that. As far as the down voting, would it be because my question doesn't show significant research effort or .....? I did not see any other similar questions, and am unfamiliar with MS Access. Just running an update on the column and calling the function slipped my mind.

Comment: It's going to be a different case patternfor different columns. That is the reason for the ambiguity of my question and responses. My question wasn't specific to a certain case pattern; it just concerned the implementation of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Table1.atext, 
       UCase(Left([atext],1)) & LCase(Mid([atext],2)) AS SConv
FROM Table1;
```

An UPDATE query BACKUP FIRST

```
UPDATE Table1 SET atext = UCase(Left([atext],1)) & LCase(Mid([atext],2)) 
WHERE AText Is Not Null
```

Note

In this case, it seems that there was a [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159684%28v=office.10%29.aspx) added to the table that forced upper case. For the most part, I reckon formats in tables should be avoided. They are more appropriate to queries and forms.

Comment: This works to give me a corresponding column with the correct capitalization. However, when trying to update the existing column, the changes aren't taking effect.

Comment: @Scott Are you familiar with SQL? You will need quite a bit to work effectively with MS Access.

Comment: Yes, and I run "Update Employees SET Employees.[Name] = strconv(Employees.[Name],3) WHERE Employees.[Name] is Not null". It does not change the name field. This is what problem I am having.

Comment: Do you really have a column called name? It is a reserved word and can cause a query to fail. You should rename the field, because Name is just about the worst reserved word to use :)

Comment: I have bracketed it any where I use it and not run into any problems with insertions or deletions anywhere(until now). I inherited this database(it's ~5 years old), and there are some design problems present. In addition to this, the Update statement I am running does not work on any of my columns, reserved word or not.

Comment: I tested both updates, mine and the strConv version and both run for me. Is this a linked table?

Comment: This is a linked table, and I am in the backend.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12912/discussion-between-remou-and-scott)

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: there is no Proper() function in Access, but there is one in Excel. Therefore use it, by referencing Excel in the VBE, and creating a function:

```
Function fProper(x As Variant)
    fProper = Excel.WorksheetFunction.proper(Nz(x))
End Function
```

**Step 2**: update your data by creating an update query similar to this one:

```
UPDATE Clients SET CompanyName = fProper([companyname]);
```

Once that works, you can start coding to automate the "for each" part, if required.

Comment: Eh? StrConv : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/strconv-function-HA001228915.aspx

Comment: Also, after running Step 2 all of his clients would be members of the "Companyname" company ;).  I believe you meant `UPDATE Clients SET CompanyName = fProper(companyname);`

Comment: To my understanding, the "proper" function for access is simply strconv(string,3)... I think I'm going to write my own that simply capitalizes the first letter of the entire string -- it will kind of bug me if the first letter of every word is capitalized. Thanks for the help though, I didn't think running an update query would work with a function I wrote, for some reason.

Comment: You're all perfectly right, sorry... I am going to sleep, I think  :-/
Did not know the StrConv(), so at least I learned something.

Comment: @Scott there is no need for a function. Straight SQL will do what you want.

Comment: I have tried "update employees set name = strconv(name,3)" to no avail..it is still all upper case.